# .Jar file in .war file does not get database connection tomcat java

Tags: java, oracle, web-services, tomcat

I have a Webservice which passes a string to a method of a jarfile. In the method are some database operations.

I created a .war file and wanted to run it in tomcat 8. But no changes are made in the database.

I googled a lot about tomcat database connections, but it looks like to me, that every tutorial is for webservice which directly use the database.

I somehow think that the jarfile should make the database connections without changes in the tomcat config or the code. in the cmd my jar is working fine.

What Informations do you need to know? I was not shure if anycode will be helpful. If you need something just tell me.

Edit:

I added the Tomcat to the eclipse environment. I created an easy webservice to test if tomcat is the problem. The answer was, that the other webservice were running in eclipse.

I created a dynamic web project added the main project as external jarfile.
I wrote the java class

```
    import javax.jws.WebMethod;

import de.morpheus.chatbot.brain.io.datasource.DataSourceDB;
import de.morpheus.chatbot.model.*;

public class WSTEST {

    private BotInit chatbot = new BotInit(new DataSourceDB());

    @WebMethod
    public String communicate(String input) {
        return this.chatbot.processInput(input);
    }
```

I right-clicked on the wetest.java in the project explorer and created the webservice.

type:Bottom UP
*StartService
*TestClient
*Monitoring the webservice

Then I clicked finish.
The Web Services Test Client window opened, and all MEthods worked except communication.
Here is the error

```
Feb 17, 2015 9:25:17 PM org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet logException
INFORMATION: Exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/morpheus/chatbot/brain/io/datasource/DataSource
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:177)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:142)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.cache.ClassCache.lookup(ClassCache.java:85)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.getServiceClass(JavaProvider.java:428)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.initServiceDesc(JavaProvider.java:461)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.getInitializedServiceDesc(SOAPService.java:286)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.makeNewInstance(WSDDService.java:500)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getService(WSDDDeployment.java:427)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getService(FileProvider.java:231)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getService(AxisEngine.java:311)
    at org.apache.axis.MessageContext.setTargetService(MessageContext.java:756)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.http.URLMapper.invoke(URLMapper.java:50)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:239)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.morpheus.chatbot.brain.io.datasource.DataSource
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    ... 48 more
```

I have to admit I have no clue, what the log is saying me.

Comment: how could jar file create database connection if its has code to do so.

Comment: in the jarfile is a method, which opens the connection and performs operations on the database system. But when I put it in the warfile and let run it on the tomcat, it will not work anymore.

Comment: are you calling that method?

Comment: yes. Do you know If I need to make any specific changes for using it on tomcat?

Comment: Do you get errors? Anything in any logs? It isn't clear what "will not work anymore" and "no changes are made in the database" really mean. You aren't really giving us anything to go on.

Comment: Where did you place the JAR? Your stacktrace indicates that the app server can't reach the jar.